Showing that a compact set in $R^2$ achieves it supremum
I am attempting to solve the following problem.
Problem:
Let $ (X, \delta) $ be a metric space and $ K $ a compact subset of $ X $. Show that there exist $ x_0, y_0 \in K $ such that
$$
\delta(x_0, y_0) = \sup \{\delta(x, y) \mid x, y \in K\}.
$$
My attempt at a solution:
Since $ K $ is compact and $ \delta $ is a metric, $ \delta(x, y) $ is bounded for all $ x, y \in K $. Thus, there exists a real number $ M \geq 0 $ such that
$$
\delta(x, y) \leq M \quad \text{for all } x, y \in K.
$$
We define $ S = \{\delta(x, y) \mid x, y \in K\} $, which is the set of all possible distances between points in $ K $. Since $ S $ is a subset of the real numbers and bounded above (by $ M $), by the completeness of the real numbers, $ S $ has a supremum. Let
$$
d = \sup S = \sup \{\delta(x, y) \mid x, y \in K\}.
$$
We need to show that there exist points $ x_0, y_0 \in K $ such that $ \delta(x_0, y_0) = d $. By the definition of the supremum, for every $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, there exist points $ x_n, y_n \in K $ such that
$$
d - \frac{1}{n} < \delta(x_n, y_n) \leq d.
$$
Since $ K $ is compact, the sequences $ (x_n) $ and $ (y_n) $ each have convergent subsequences. Let $ (x_{n_k}) $ and $ (y_{n_k}) $ be such that
$$
x_{n_k} \to x_0 \quad \text{and} \quad y_{n_k} \to y_0 \quad \text{as} \quad k \to \infty,
$$
for some $ x_0, y_0 \in K $ (compactness ensures that the limit points $ x_0 $ and $ y_0 $ lie within $ K $).
Since $ \delta $ is continuous, we have
$$
\delta(x_0, y_0) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \delta(x_{n_k}, y_{n_k}).
$$
By the way we chose $ x_{n_k} $ and $ y_{n_k} $, we know that
$$
d - \frac{1}{n_k} < \delta(x_{n_k}, y_{n_k}) \leq d.
$$
Taking the limit as $ k \to \infty $, by the squeeze theorem we get
$$
\delta(x_0, y_0) = d.
$$
Therefore, there exist $ x_0, y_0 \in K $ such that $ \delta(x_0, y_0) = \sup \{\delta(x, y) \mid x, y \in K\} $.
Is this proof correct or are there any errors with it? Are there any alternate methods to prove the statement?
Thank you for your support.

yes, looks good to me.

No, the proof is not correct. The problem appears when you state that “the sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ each have convergent subsequences” (which is correct) and then add that you take subsequences $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ and $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ which converge to $x_0$ and to $y_0$ respectively. The only obvious thing is that there are convergent subsequences $(x_{\color{blue}{n_k}})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ and $(y_{\color{red}{m_k}})_{k\in\Bbb N}$, but the indexes don't have to be the same.
Yet it is indeed true that there is some strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ of natural numbers such that both $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ and $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ which converge. In fact, you know that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ has some convergent subsequences $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ and then you can use the fact that the sequence $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ (which doesn't have to be convergent) has, in turn, some convergent subsequence $(y_{m_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$. And, of course, since the sequence $(x_{m_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is a subsequence of $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$, it is also convergent.

Let us define (xn, yxn) as a sequence where yxn is the point that maximizes the distance among all y from xn. Let d(x0, yx0) be the maximum distance between any two points on the compact set and consider a sequence (xn) converging to x0.

My understanding is that we must find a sequence (xnk)k∈N that converges to x0 where d(x0, yx0) (with yx0 being the point that maximizes the distance from x0) maximizes the distance between any two points on the compact set. I am having difficulty understanding why we need to pass to a further subsequence, and why we cannot assume that if the y indices are the same then the sequence converges to (x0, yx0), and also how we know that if we take a further subsequence of those with the x indices we know that it necessarily converges to yx0. Could you provide any examples to understand this better?

Suppose that $(a_n){n\in\Bbb N}$ is the sequence $1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1\ldots$ and that $(b_n){n\in\Bbb N}$ is the sequence $1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1\ldots$. Does the sequence $((a_n,b_n)){n\in\Bbb N}$ have a convergent subsequence? Well, the sequence $(a{3n}){n\in\Bbb N}$ converges (to $0$). However, the sequence  $((a{3n},b_{3n})){n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converge. In order to get a convergent subsequence of $((a_n,b_n)){n\in\Bbb N}$ you have to take a subsequence of $((a_{3n},b_{3n})){n\in\Bbb N}$, such as $((a{6n},b_{6n}))_{n\in\Bbb N}$. I hope that this makes my objection clear.
